# handlebars.js does not work at all

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, handlebars.js

I am using mustache as a template engine. And I want to use handlebars.js, but handlebars.js does not work at all. The path is correct.

I think handlebars.js and mustache are in conflict on my project...

Currently it does not work on our project. I wonder it bacause of mustache template engine.  handlebars.js works well for projects created with jsfiddle or javascript. With the same code.`enter code here`

I wonder if there is any way to avoid conflicts or other ways.

This is my environmet: spring boot 1.5.9, mustache template engine

```
   $(document).on("keyup", "input[name='search_member']",function() {
        $(".edge_search_list").show();
        $(".search_list").show();

        var email_pattern = $("input[name='search_member']").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/searchMember/" + email_pattern,
            dataType: "text",
            beforeSend:function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".btn_search").css('background','url("../../resources/images/gif/ajax_loading.gif") no-repeat 5px center/contain');
                },300);

            },
            success: function(data) {
                var context = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(context);
                if(context.length > 0) {
                    var target =  $("#search-template").html();
                    var template = Handlebars.compile(target);
                    var html = "";
                    for(var i =0;i<context.length;i++){
                        html = html + template(context);
                        $(".search_list").html(html);

                    }
                } else {
                    var html2 = $("#search-template2").html();
                    $(".search_list").html(html2);
                }


            },
            complete:function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".btn_search").css('background','url("../../resources/images/icon/search_btn.png") no-repeat 5px center/contain');
                },1500);
            }
        });
    });
```

---

```
<script id="search-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="search_user_data">
    <div>
        <img src="{{#search_thumbnail}}{{search_thumbnail}}{{/search_thumbnail}}{{^search_thumbnail}}../../../resources/images/default-person.gif{{/search_thumbnail}}" alt="ㅁㅁㅁ님">
    </div>
    <div class="search_info left">

        <div>{{#search_email}}{{search_email}}{{/search_email}}null@naver.com</div>
        <div>{{#search_name}}{{search_name}}{{/search_name}}홍길동<span class="invitation_status">(초대됨)</span></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn_search_invite">취소</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON RESULT with console.log()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGlQg.jpg)

Comment: You should show the specific code that you are using, such that people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "it doesn't work" means? You included the tag "syntax error", does that mean you are getting an error message somewhere? If so, please [edit] your question to include the exact error message, and if possible a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: oh sorry wait plz.